# Better way to diff changes that made to a specific branch without merged commits?

Tags: git, git-diff

I am try to do a code review for my current branch `feat`, which is based on branch `develop`.

I want to combine all changes made to that branch compare to the staring point (Let's say the hash is `a483b4b38` on `develop` branch).

The thing is, `develop` branch also has some commits during the `feat` development, and I merged `develop` into `feat` serveral times during development.

Is there a way to separate a branch from commmit `a483b4b38` and includes all changes made to `feat` branch but without `develop` merges? I just want to check all changes that purely made by myself on that branch.

Comment: Just do `git diff the-upstream...my-branch` (notice it's `...`, not `..`).. It should work fine if you did _real_ merges (unlike squashed merges) of `develop` into your branch. If you did squash-merges, then you need to clean up your branch from those commits (preferred tool for that is `git rebase -i`).

Comment: This is obviously impossible in general: what if the last change on `feat` changes a line introduced by a merge from `develop` that doesn't exist in a483b4b38?  What would the diff say then?

Comment: At first, I thought that `...` would not work because of the merges _but_ then I remembered that mething moves the latest common ancestor which makes `...` still work as expected and required in this scenario.

Comment: @DavisHerring it's not impossible. That's what `...` is used for. It would be the same as diffing against the last commit that has been merged from `develop` using a normal `..`, actually.

Comment: Actually, considering the mental process I had to go through to reach the answer, I must have had a lapsus cause it's actually not too difficult of an scenario to solve :D

Comment: @eftshift0: The result of that `git diff` using `...` will not in general apply to the _original_ base commit of the branch, which is the problem stated.

Comment: Well, if the OP is _fixed_ on comparing against that commit, then the only thing that will work is to clean up the branch.

Comment: I ended up starting a branch from `a483b4b38` and cherry-picked all commits that authored by myself on that branch manually. I did encounter some conflicts but resolved them manually. I'm just curious if there's a better way to do it

Comment: if you mean, cleaning up the branch? `git rebase -i` would also be handy in terms of getting a list of commits and then being able to choose to pick/skip them from the comfort of a text editor. If you mean, being able to know what you did in the branch as if it were a PR in a given provider, then diff with `...` is your friend, no need to clean up the branch.

Comment: @DavisHerring: while it is true that `a483b4b38` isn't the base for the diff, `git diff develop...my-branch` will show the (correct and complete) view of all changes that will be brought to the `develop` branch. I would argue that it is more accurate than trying to build a sequence of patches on top of a past state of develop, which is an outdated reference anyway.

Comment: @HaoWu: would you be comfortable with all your changes squashed in one commit on top of *the last state of develop which you merged* ?

Comment: @LeGEC Not the last state of `develop` branch, since `feat` has already been merged into the `develop` branch... several times. So I wanted to compare all the changes(without merges) based on the point I created the `feat` branch

Comment: In your question you mention merges from `develop` into `feat`. Did you also merge the other way around ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, `feat` and `develop` are practically the same contents right now, that’s why I’m struggling to get all the pure commit diffs from `feat` to its starting point

Comment: The fact that you also merged `feat` back into `develop` is extremely relevant to the question, and currently isn't mentioned outside of the comments.

Comment: Also, I believe the back and forth between @DavisHerring and eftshift0 is because they are both correct, and the two sentences in your last paragraph conflict with each other. This is because "all changes that purely made by myself on that branch" could very well be against code only brought in by a `develop` merge. eftshift0's 3 dot diff is normally exactly what you would want (e.g. `git diff develop...feat` ), however, since you're already merged `feat` back into `develop` multiple times, you may need to repeat that 3-dot diff before each merge commit, against the first and second parent.

Comment: Side note, when looking at the merge commits on `develop` where `feat` was merged in, you could also just compare that MC with it's first parent, which would be equivalent to the 3 dot diff of the two parents. For example, `git diff MC~1 MC` should equal `git diff MC^1...MC^2`. You still need to repeat that on every commit where you merged `feat` into `develop`, after `a483b4b38`. (Note the space between the commits is the same as two dots. So it's 2 dots vs 3 dots also.)